# Restore exact Recyclerview position -- with list of items with different sizes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

After trying many solutions, I still was not able to solve the issue. Please help.

My Android app has a Recyclerview with a list of large items. An item could be 2 lines or 35.

When switching from the Recyclerview screen to another screen, I want to save the exact location, so I can go back to the exact same position.

Of course I spent many hours looking for the solution, without finding a definite solution. A few solutions are shown below:

1 - Using: computeVerticalScrollOffset:

```
int offset = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset();
```

2 - Using: findFirstVisibleItemPosition and getTop() and paddingTop()

```
int index = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
View v = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
int offset = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - recyclerView.getPaddingTop());
```

3 - Using findFirstVisibleItemPosition and getTop()

```
int firstVisiblePosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
View visibleEntry = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition( firstVisiblePosition);
int offset = visibleEntry.getTop();
```

Using these positions I could scroll to the exact location with:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition( index);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.scrollBy(0, - offset);
        }
    }, 500);
```

All versions are not correct.

How to solve the current location ... and restore it easily?

There is a simple solution for the ListView, but of course I don't want to go back to the ListView ;-)

Comment: Have you tried to obtain save state parcelable with `linearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState()` then using it to restore state with `linearLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState`?

Comment: Thank you for helping!! This solution would be my last known possibility; I found it a bit heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a really good answer!

Saving the 'location' was a known solution:

```
int position = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
View visibleChildView = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
int offset = (visibleChildView  == null) ? 0 : (visibleChildView .getTop() - recyclerView.getPaddingTop());
```

**BUT**, using the location via the linearLayoutManager was new to me:

```
if ( position != -1) {  
    linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset( position, offset);
}
```

Surprisingly, this option looks very much like the good-old Listview solution ;-)